# The contents of .git/config after git branch -t x y/z

Tags: git

Suppose that `scratch` is a remote repo and `bough` is a branch in this repo.  This means that one of the lines printed by `git branch -r` will be `scratch/bough`.  If now I execute

```
% git branch -t twig scratch/bough
Branch twig set up to track remote branch bough from scratch.
```

and then examine the contents of `.git/config`, I see that a new section has been added to it:

```
[branch "twig"]
        remote = scratch
        merge = refs/heads/bough
```

The value of the `merge` attribute may lead one to believe that there is a file `.git/refs/heads/bough`, but in fact *there is no such file*.  But there *is* now a file `.git/refs/heads/twig`:

```
.git/refs
├── heads
│   ├── master
│   └── twig
├── remotes
│   └── scratch
│       └── HEAD
└── tags
```

This makes me realize that either the line `merge = refs/heads/bough` does not mean why I thought it did (IOW, that the value referred to the path, relative to `.git`, of an existing file), or else there's a pretty significant bug in git.

So, let's assume that the former is the case.  What then does the line `merge = refs/heads/bough` really mean?

Comment: i just had to +1 your question because of `scratch/HEAD` xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `merge` line is referring to a ref present in the remote repo, not in the local repo. The local upstream branch for `twig` is actually going to be `refs/remotes/scratch/bough`.

And for the record, not all refs live as files in `.git/refs`. You can have packed refs that live in `.git/packed-refs` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
[branch "twig"]
    remote = scratch
    merge = refs/heads/bough
```

This block means the following: The *local* branch `twig` is set to have an upstream branch `bough` on the remote `scratch`, i.e. `scratch/bough` is the remote tracking branch. So e.g. when you push while being on `twig` it will push to `scratch/bough`.